# How do I solve this Expected: ")" pylance error I am getting with an f string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

With this particular issue I am doing something a course wants me to do for string interpolation.

It tells me to take the following:

```
# 4. print "I love to eat sushi and pizza." with the foods in variables
fave_food1 = "sushi"
fave_food2 = "pizza"
```

and use an f string

```
print(f"I love to eat {fave_food1} and {fave_food2}.")
```

For some reason I am getting the following:
[image: screen shot of issue]

can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? This is my first time doing anything with Python in about 8 years. I do not know why I am getting this? Is there something "small" I'm overlooking?

I have experience with other languages (mainly c type) but there's nothing that I can see that would need an addition ')'. I've researched the issue but there's nothing for this specific issue that I can find.

Thank you

Comment: I can't rep. By Pylance, I assume you are using VS Code. If so, what is the python version shown on the status bar on the lower left side of the IDE? And just to confirm, did you make sure to save the file after entering that line of code?

Comment: It could be caused by the previous line. Is this all you have?

Comment: Can you paste few lines of code before and after this? Also the complete error msg..

Comment: I am using Python 3.9.5 (or .6). I will check when I get back home.  My power has been out due to a storm that came through.

Comment: I created the two variables in cmd and then ran the print() function with the f string and it worked just fine. Appears to be something wrong with the file/VS Code. If I try to run the file in cmd I get a SyntaxError.

Comment: @Selcuk, you are correct, it was a previous line. The course had me also use variables in a string using .format() at the end, after the .format() I forgot to put the closing ')'. This has me convinced at this point I need to go see an optometrist

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

This block of code works perfectly on my VS Code.
You might want to check the version of python you are using and try to update it. Also, make sure the file and code are properly saved and the file is in the right folder before running the code.

```
#4. print "I love to eat sushi and pizza." with the foods in variables

fave_food1 = "sushi"
fave_food2 = "pizza"
print(f"I love to eat {fave_food1} and {fave_food2}.")
```

**output**

```
I love to eat sushi and pizza.
```

Comment: I believe I am using the most recent version 3.9.5 (or .6) my power has been out due to a storm.